# Want to display an auto generated id in a custom module of SugarCRM

Tags: triggers, sugarcrm, auto-generate

I am using Sugar Enterprise 6.4.0 and want to display a uneditable field in a custom module Edit and Detail view. This id need to be generated automatcially and need to be displayed in the interface when user click to create a new record in the custom module.

Because i am new to Sugar can anyone help me out in performing this task. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the readonly property on the field itself in the vardefs for the module...

```
$dictionary['<<module>>']['fields']['<<fieldname>>']['readonly'] = true;
```

Then, add some logic in the custom/modules/<>/views/view.edit.php which does the autogeneration for you.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this, using an after_save_hook with code like(not exact):

```
$bean->name = $bean->id;
```

as soon as you save a record in sugar an id is generated automatically. Then I don't include the ID in the editview at all, just the detail and list views. I don't see any point in including it in the edit view as it is not editable.